# Send message to consumer when connected to ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I have multiple instances of a worker connected to a queue and all requests will be distributed to worker instances in a load balanced way. When a new worker instance is connected to the queue, I should dump a small data from mainstream app to this new worker instance (one time job).

Currently I'm using REST endpoint from mainstream app for doing this at application start-up but can we leverage the messaging queue for this? Once a new worker instance connected to queue, it will ask the initial data dump to mainstream app through queue and then app will reply with initial data.

Is it possible using messaging queue/topic? Kindly share your views/suggestions to achieve this using activemq

Comment: Thank you @JustinBertram I'm not aware that classic amq is not support these semantics so I'm stick with REST

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActiveMQ Artemis this kind of requirement is typically fulfilled with a queue that supports both [non-destructive](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/docs/user-manual/en/non-destructive-queues.md) and [last-value](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/docs/user-manual/en/last-value-queues.md) semantics. The last-value semantics allows the queue to stay up-to-date with the latest messages and the non-destructive semantics means that even when consumers acknowledge the messages they will remain on the queue for the next client which connects. When using this combination clients can first consume all the messages from this special "initialization" queue and then continue on with whatever other messaging work they need to do.

Unfortunately ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't support either of these semantics and there is no straight-forward way to get equivalent behavior.